# Bindings not updating after changing value in loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following ViewModel for a small Knockout screen I am working on.  In the UI there is a "cancel" button which calls `viewModel.cancel()` (below).  The `cancel` function does what it's supposed to do (removes item from one collection and iterates through another to set the selected property), but the UI never gets updated.

```
var tag = function(id, text){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.text = text;
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);

    self.unselect = function() {
        self.selected = false;
    }
};

var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.tags = ko.observableArray([
        new tag(100, "Tag100"),
        new tag(200, "Tag200"),
        new tag(300, "Tag300"),
        new tag(400, "Tag400"),
        new tag(500, "Tag500"),
        new tag(600, "Tag600")
    ]);

    self.selectedTags = ko.observableArray();

    self.childClick = function(tag){
        self.selectedTags.remove(tag);

        if (tag.selected){
            self.selectedTags.push(tag);
        }

        return true;
    };

    self.showApply = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.selectedTags().length > 0;
    });

    self.cancel = function(){

        this.selectedTags.removeAll();

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.tags(), function(tag) {
            tag.unselect();
        });

        //when this finishes, selectedTags is empty and calling ko.toJSON(viewModel) shows that the selected value is reset -- the UI just doesn't reflect this.

    };

};
```

The html is fairly straightforward

```
 <div id="tagDropdown" class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Add Tag<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form">
            <li data-bind="foreach: tags">
                <div>
                    <div class="tagCheck"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: selected, click: $root.childClick" /></div>
                    <div class="tagText" data-bind="text: text"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="separator"></div>

                <button data-bind="visible: showApply">Apply</button>
                <button data-bind="visible: showApply, click: cancel">Cancel</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Given the popularity of the library and the competence of team working on it, I'm sure it's something that I'm doing wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the unselect function with

```js
self.unselect = function() {
    self.selected(false);
}
```

Never ever replace an obserable object. Always reset the value calling it as a function with the new value.

Comment: Wow - I'm ebarassed at the time spent frustrated to the ease of solution ratio on this :)   Many thanks!